# Finding the outlier number

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to solve a coding challenge over on `CodeWars.com` and I was hoping to get a little nudge in the right direction. The following function is supposed to take a string of numbers (like `"2 4 7 8 10"`, or `"1 2 2"` etc.) and output the position of the number that is different in evenness (even or odd) than the others. The `CodeWars.com` link to this is at: https://www.codewars.com/kata/iq-test/train/javascript)

My function seems to be failing on tests where the last number is the number that is different (`"100 100 1"` or `"5 3 2"`).  Any ideas why my function is performing this way?  I've been looking at it and I can't see why it would be doing this:

```js
function iqTest(numbers){
  let numArr = numbers.split(' ');
  let obj = {};
  obj.evenCount = 0;
  obj.oddCount = 0;
  console.log(numArr);

  for (let i = 0; i < numArr.length; i++) {
    if (numArr[i] % 2 === 0) {
      obj.evenCount += 1;
      obj.even = i + 1;
    } else {
      obj.oddCount += 1;
      obj.odd = i + 1;
    }
  }

  if (obj.even < obj.odd) {
    return (obj.even);
  } else {
    return (obj.odd);
  }
}

console.log(iqTest('5 3 2'));
```

Comment: Could you add a link to the particular kata on CodeWars?

Comment: @Tyler, they are how I am determining which type of number (even/odd) makes up the majority of the string and which type is the outlier.  Figured which ever is less is the type of number that only appears once.

Comment: @BrianHernandez That's not what that code is doing. To determine which is the majority, you want to compare the *counts* (`evenCount` and `oddCount`), not the *position*.

Comment: @TylerRoper ah, that's what I wasn't seeing.  Thank you.  I will try Spencer's suggestion as well, to see if I can improve my function.  Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check the `eventCount` and `oddCount` at the end of your function, not the `odd` and `event` properties like so:

```
if (obj.evenCount < obj.oddCount) {
```

Before, you were checking which index is higher (ie the position), but really you want to check which count/frequency is higher.

See working example below:

```js
function iqTest(numbers) {
  let numArr = numbers.split(' ');
  let obj = {};
  obj.evenCount = 0;
  obj.oddCount = 0;
  console.log(numArr);

  for (let i = 0; i < numArr.length; i++) {
    if (numArr[i] % 2 === 0) {
      obj.evenCount += 1;
      obj.even = i + 1;
    } else {
      obj.oddCount += 1;
      obj.odd = i + 1;
    }
    
    if(obj.oddCount > 0 && obj.evenCount > 0 && obj.oddCount !== obj.evenCount) { // early termination condition
      break; // break out of the loop is the difference between odd and even already exists
    }
  }

  if (obj.evenCount < obj.oddCount) { // change to check the counts
    return (obj.even);
  } else {
    return (obj.odd);
  }
}

console.log(iqTest("2 4 7 8 10")); // 3 (item: 7)
console.log(iqTest("1 2 2")); // 1 (item: 1)
console.log(iqTest("100 100 1")); // 3 (item: 1)
console.log(iqTest("5 3 2")); // 3 (item: 2)
```

Comment: Good one dude! Maybe you can break the loop soon, when you have the condition: `obj.oddCount > 0 && obj.evenCount > 0 && obj.oddCount !== obj.evenCount`

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, the issue in your code is that  you're trying to determine which is the majority (odd or even), but you do this by comparing the *last occurrence position* (`obj.odd` and `obj.even`) rather than the *amount of occurrences* (`obj.evenCount` and `obj.oddCount`).

Simply change it to this: `if (obj.evenCount < obj.oddCount) { ... }`

---

That said, your function will *always* look through the entire array, however you can determine whether the outlier is even or odd just by *looking at the first three numbers*. Whichever appears less, even or odd, is the outlier.

With that in mind, we can make this more efficient by breaking it into two steps:

1. Use the first three numbers to determine if the outlier is `odd` or `even`.
2. Exit when we find the first occurrence of that outlier, rather than searching the entire array.

```js
function iqTest(stringOfNumbers) {
    let arr = stringOfNumbers.split(' ');
    let desiredRemainder = arr
      .slice(0,3)
      .reduce((evenCount, item) => item % 2 === 0 ? evenCount+1 : evenCount, 0) 
        > 1
          ? 1
          : 0;
    return arr.findIndex(i => i % 2 === desiredRemainder) + 1;
}
    
console.log(iqTest("3 4 7 9"));
console.log(iqTest("1 1 1 100"));
console.log(iqTest("5 2 3"));
```

Here's a slightly more verbose version to break-out the steps into meaningful variable names:

```js
function iqTest(stringOfNumbers) {
    let arr = stringOfNumbers.split(' ');
    let firstThree = arr.slice(0,3);
    let evenCount = firstThree.reduce((evenCount, item) => item % 2 === 0 ? evenCount+1 : evenCount, 0);
    let desiredRemainder = evenCount > 1 ? 1 : 0;
    let indexOfOutlier = arr.findIndex(i => i % 2 === desiredRemainder);
    return  indexOfOutlier+1;
}
    
console.log(iqTest("3 4 7 9"));
console.log(iqTest("1 1 1 100"));
console.log(iqTest("5 2 3"));
```

1. I use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce%60) to determine whether we have more odds or evens.
2. If the outlier is odd, we're looking for the first item where `item % 2 === 1` (an odd number).

   If the outlier is even, we're looking for the first item where `item % 2 === 0` (an even number).
3. I then put that logic in [`Array.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex), which will return the position of the first item in which the given test is `true` (and I add `1` to it to replicate your code).

Answer (score 1):

Based on this condition of the data:

> Find out which one of the given numbers differs from the others. Bob observed that **one number** usually **differs** from the others in **evenness**

I'm going to give an alternative approach using the built-in array methods, for a standard approach, refer to **Nick Parsons** answer:

```js
function iqTest(numbers)
{
    return 1 + numbers.split(" ").findIndex(
        (x, idx, arr) => arr.filter(y => y % 2 === x % 2).length === 1
    );
}

console.log(iqTest("2 4 7 8 10")); // 3 (item: 7)
console.log(iqTest("1 2 2")); // 1 (item: 1)
console.log(iqTest("100 100 1")); // 3 (item: 1)
console.log(iqTest("5 3 2")); // 3 (item: 2)
```